# making parameter from 2 strings in vba Access

Tags: ms-access, parameters, vba

To create this year table my code is:

```
SQL = "select * into table_log2016 from table_log "
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

I want to put a parameter instead of `table_log2016` consisting table_log and `Right(Date,4)` which is 2016 this year. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should do it:
SQL = "select * into table_log" & Right(Date, 4) & " from table_log"